# There are 45 egg boxes in a store.

Tags: probability

Twenty are Brand A, fifteen are brand B, and ten are Brand C. Brand A and C each have half green boxes and half yellow boxes. Brand B is all yellow.

If you have Brand B or C, what's the chance that you have a green box?

My work:

let $G$ be the event that the box is green, $B$ be the event that the box is from brand B, $C$ be the event that the box is from brand C.

I believe that we are trying to calculate $P(G \cap (B \cup C)) = P(G\cap B) \cup P(G\cap C)$ via the distributive law

So $P(G\cap B) = 0 $ since all of Brand B has yellow boxes. and $P(G\cap C) = P(C)P(G|C) = \cfrac{10}{45} \cdot \cfrac{1}{2} = \cfrac{1}{9}$

so $P(G \cap (B \cup C)) = 0 + \cfrac{1}{9} = \cfrac{1}{9}$ is the probability

But the book says that $1/5$ is the probability.

Can someone show me where I went wrong in my reasoning? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have computed the probability that you chose $B$ or $C$ and that you got a green box. You are given that you have $B$ or $C$.
$$
\overbrace{\quad\frac{15}{25}\quad}^{P(B|B\lor C)}\cdot\overbrace{\ \quad0\quad\ \vphantom{\frac11}}^{P(G|B)}+\overbrace{\quad\frac{10}{25}\quad}^{P(C|B\lor C)}\cdot\overbrace{\ \quad\frac12\quad\ }^{P(G|C)}=\overbrace{\ \quad\frac15\quad\ }^{P(G|B\lor C)}
$$

Comment: Oh I see my misinterpretation now. Thank You! I'll accept your answer when I can

Answer (score 1):

There are 10 boxes in C, of which 5 are green. None of the 15 in B are green.

If you select from either B or C, then you have 5 green boxes and 10 + 15 = 25 total items, so 5/25 or 1/5.

Comment: @BillBillwater correct — you’re calculating a conditional probability where you know it’s from B or C.

Comment: You don't *know* that 5 of the C boxes are green, but it's enough that you can *expect* that.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I thought we do know this (I.e., we are given sample statistics in the problem): we are told there are 10 boxes of C and half of them are green.